# Exporting AAR. from an Complex Project

Tags: android, aar

I have a problem about exporting AAR from my project. My project has 3 modules that included as library into the project. One of that modules is android project that contains the actual project.

That means when you run the whole project in AVD, project opens the module as I mentioned before. And the other modules related and connected with the main module as a network and opencv library.

My problem is: When I want to create ONE AAR. file that includes all modules inside, the android project creates AAR. file by module that means three different AAR. file for 3 different module.

Because of that I cannot add my whole project's AAR. file to another project.

There is way of creating AAR. file of whole project that includes all modules inside like opencv module, network module, for all modules?
My project build.gradle;

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/dependencyVersion.gradle"

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.17.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"}
    }
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

}

artifactoryPublish.skip = true

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my build.gradle. of the library module. Lets call it module1 where i want to merge all other two library module(module2, module3) into this module1.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


version = rootProject.sdkVersionName
group = rootProject.mainLibraryGroup

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVer

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVer
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVer
        versionCode rootProject.sdkVersionCode
        versionName rootProject.sdkVersionName
//        versionCode 1
//        versionName "1.0.0(10)"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            // The libs directory contains prebuilt libraries that are used by the app's library defined in CMakeLists.txt
            // via an IMPORTED target.
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs'] //'libs'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    
//    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(path: ':module2')
    implementation project(path: ':module3')

    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"

    //getting dependencies from dependencies.gradle file
    implementation deps.crashlytics
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$versions.arcLifecycle"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$versions.glide"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$versions.appcompat"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$versions.constraintLayout"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$versions.gson"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$versions.material"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$versions.okHttp"
    implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.0-alpha01"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$versions.playServices"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-text-recognition:$versions.playServices"

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'org.jmrtd:jmrtd:0.7.18'
    implementation 'net.sf.scuba:scuba-sc-android:0.0.20'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0'

    implementation 'edu.ucar:jj2000:5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.mhshams:jnbis:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-beta05'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta05'

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.4"
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    //RX
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$versions.rxandroid"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$versions.rxjava"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'


    //image Cropping



    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'




}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


apply from: "$rootProject.projectDir/tools/artifactory/commonArtifactory.gradle"
```

I applied all of them. After that, i clicked the gradle in righ panel of Android Studi. And I selected the module1>other>assembleRelease. I gave me this error.

```
 DSL element 'android.dataBinding.enabled' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'android.buildFeatures.dataBinding'.
Could not resolve io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:null
```

Comment: Is difficult to follow what you are asking. Please consider do a grammar check before you post.

Comment: My problem is I cannot export one aar file that includes all modules. When i try to export aar. android studio gives me 3 aar. file for three modules! Thats my problem, you got it?

Answer (score 1):

You need a fat-aar (An aar that includes all the others locally).
You can use something like [kezong lib](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android) or [cpdroid lib](https://github.com/cpdroid/fat-aar)

**Update**:

Based on the snippet that you included in the question, I suggest to try the changes below:

In your root `build-gradle` file (I think that is the first snippet) you should add the below code:

```
dependencies {     
        classpath 'com.kezong:fat-aar:1.2.20'
}
```

In your library's `build-gradle` file you should add the

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.kezong.fat-aar'
```

and change the below dependencies section:

**from**

```
dependencies {
   implementation project(path: ':module2')
   implementation project(path: ':module3')
}
```

**to**

```
dependencies {
   releaseEmbed project(path: ':module2')
   releaseEmbed project(path: ':module3')

   debugImplementation project(path: ':module2')
   debugImplementation project(path: ':module3')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Did u use one of them before? Is it safe? And which one is better?

Comment: Both of them do the some job. I have used the kezong lib for a project and it's as simple as it looks.

Comment: Oh, OK kenzong is okay then. But i couldnt get clearly the install steps to get plugin of kenzog. I have some questions about install steps of kenzong. In step 1 of plugin; First of all, i have to download the plugin file and add to android studio from plugin page manually? And then the other question is  about the 2. step: Embed dependencies... Where is this Embed dependencies in the project? And how can i do step two? Just copy and paste all code or i have to make some changing in the code?

Comment: You should follow the steps for the installs, you shouldn't do anything manually. First add the classpaths in the root build script and then apply plugin. Replace the "implementation" to "embed" for the dependencies you want.

Comment: Oh, you skipping fastly i still couldn't undestand clearly. :). Let me explain what i understood. First, i added the classpathes in the root build. And then apply the plugin? Will i apply plugin to the root of project or apply for all modules that i want to merge. Also where i'm gonna do this step: replacing the 'implementation" to "embed". Let's say i have module1 module2 and module3 in the main app. So, i want to merge all modules in just only one aar. How should i replace for dependencies in step2?

Comment: Also when i repleced implementation with embed. I got an error "Couldnt find embed methods...".

Comment: You would apply the plugin in the `build.gradle` of your android library and not in root ([example](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android/blob/master/example/lib-main/build.gradle)). Then use both `releaseEmbed` & `debugImplementation` for the libraries in order to include them inside the release AAR and also use the them with the remote dependency in the debug builds and not have any error.

Comment: Yes, I did all you said to me. But im getting a different error: " Could not find method flavor1Embed() for arguments [project ': blablabla'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler
"

Comment: What does "local full aar dependency"? What should i put in this line? Should i put my main module into it? i did like that but not worked.

Comment: I really want to help you, but I should see snippet of code in order to understand what you are doing wrong. I would propose, to flag as answered this topic and go and edit the other one that you have created, add your `build.gradle` files (root & lib) and explain the structure that you want. I am going to continue my answers there.

Comment: I added my project's build.gradle and my module's(module1) build gradle. I have three module **module1** **module2** **module3**. **module1** is an android project that i used as a library in main project. **module2** contains openCv codes. **module3** is also allows network with server as a library. I want a aar file that contains all module: **module1** **module2** **module3**. So i can use this aar in another project. You can reach my pure codes without adding this plugin.  @frontz

Comment: I have attached snippet of code based on yours

Comment: Thank you so much! I applied all of them. After that, i clicked the gradle in righ panel of Android Studi. And I selected the module1>other>assembleRelease. I gave me error. What i did wrong?

Comment: You should understand that you should close a question and proceed to another one. The error that you have is irrelevant from the starting question. The `$versions.rxandroid` is null, just hardcode the RXandroid version that you want in the dependency and it will work.